# Unable to install MongoDB in Windows 32-bit OS

Tags: mongodb

I have tried to install MongoDB in my windows machine. But it fails saying that it requires 64-bit OS.

But I am having 32-bit OS only. Is there any MongoDB versions that is suitable for 32-bit OS?

Need someones help.

Comment: Is this not helping you: https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/i386 ?

Comment: am getting version mismatch error...

Comment: Paste your error too.